# BJTs to drive N-Fet

Tags: mosfet, bjt

I stopped using BJTs for a while and now I can't figure out why this configuration does not give me a 12 V PWM  at the gate of the MOSFET? I am only getting slightly more than my PWM voltage about 4.2 V.

I have tried resistors at the gate to limit current and different resistors at the PWM for some input impedance but nothing. If I am not mistaken, when the top transistor is on it should effectively close that "switch" and I should get my 12 V at the gate.
Maybe I've spent too much time playing with MOSFETs and I have forgotten how BJTs work.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ff94qD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Try adapting [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/360918/help-with-bjt-based-driver-for-mosfet/360930#360930). It's close.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your BJTs are configured as followers so the gate signal will be smaller than the drive by a diode drop each way. Perhaps add a common emitter amplifier between the drive signal and Q1/Q2 to boost the amplitude to near 12 V peak to peak.

Comment: oh I see, I remember that term from a couple of semesters ago. I think I need to hit the textbooks for a refresher to see how that is so.